# Reading a words from file with a stream

Tags: java, file-io, stream

I am trying to read the words of a file into a stream and the count the number of times the word "the" appears in the file. I cannot seem to figure out an efficient way of doing this with only streams.

Example: If the file contained a sentence such as: "The boy jumped over the river." the output would be 2

This is what I've tried so far

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    String filename = "input1";
    try (Stream<String> words = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename))){
        long count = words.filter( w -> w.equalsIgnoreCase("the"))
                .count();
        System.out.println(count);
    } catch (IOException e){

    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide us with code samples of what you tried until now. That way we can help you more effectively.

Answer (score 1):

Just line name suggests `Files.lines` returns stream of *lines* not words. If you want to iterate over words I you can use `Scanner` like

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fileLocation));
while(sc.hasNext()){
    String word = sc.next();
    //handle word
}
```

If you really want to use streams you can split each line and then map your stream to those words

```
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename))){
    long count = lines
            .flatMap(line->Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s+"))) //add this
            .filter( w -> w.equalsIgnoreCase("the"))
            .count();
    System.out.println(count);
} catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();//at least print exception so you would know what wend wrong
}
```

BTW you shouldn't leave empty catch blocks, at least print exception which was throw so you would have more info about problem.

Comment: does the regular expression in the .split command also split along new line characters like a break between paragraphs for instance?

Comment: @AddisonWaege Most likely. `\s` represents wide range of white spaces and is usually sufficient for this kind of tasks. Test it and you will find out.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Java's [StreamTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html) for this purpose.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StreamTokenizer;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      long theWordCount = 0;
      String input = "The boy jumped over the river.";
      try (InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
             input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()))) {
        StreamTokenizer tokenizer = 
          new StreamTokenizer(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            int tokenType = 0;
            while ( (tokenType = tokenizer.nextToken()) 
               != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
                if (tokenType == StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD) {
                    String word = tokenizer.sval;
                    if ("the".equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {
                        theWordCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The word 'the' count is: " + theWordCount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the stream reader to calculate the number of words.